# Escape comma in regular expression - Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have multiple snippets of C code similar to

```
const stFunctions m_fun = {
    NULL,

    &fun_1,
    &fun_2,

    NULL,

    &fun_3
};
```

I am trying to replace all `NULL,` using the `NULL,\n\n` regular expression in Notepad++ but it doesn't seem to work. I tried `NULL,` and `\n\n` and they both work.

Comment: Try `^\h*NULL,\R{2}`. Actually, you should be very careful when modifying source code with a regex like this.

Comment: Yeah, that works, thanks!

Comment: What do you want to replace the NULL lines with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be very careful when modifying source code with a regex. If you are sure that you want to remove whole lines with just `NULL,` in them and an empty line below that line, you may use

```
^\h*NULL,\h*\R{2}
```

The regex matches

- `^` - start of a line
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `NULL,` - a `NULL,` string
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\R{2}` - 2 line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use regex!

The characters you’re searching for do not require regex. Select “extended characters” and search for `NULL,\r\n` (Windows) or `NULL,\n` (*nix) and replace with whatever you want to replace it with.